# What does "LOA" stand for?

Tags: support, flagging

I recently flagged something up as `very low quality`, but my flag was declined. When I looked at the reason this is what it said:

[image: LOA]

So what does `LOA` stand for?

Comment: Link Only Answer?

Comment: @markkirby: Oh... Probably yes! Please post that as an answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: @ParanoidPanda or why do you not delete this lack of knowledge >:-D There should be a generic topic on this too. I know I saw one somewhere on a META.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a comment on the answer that said it was a link-only answer. I assumed your flag was for the same because it did appear to offer a solution.

It needed explaining so I edited and rejected your flag. It's not a perfect answer but it's a lot higher than the bar for "very low quality" should be.

---

On a related note, I've been rejecting a few moderator flags today because people are being excessively lazy. Yours is not the best example because it did need a bit of work, but **don't use flags to deal with things when editing, commenting and voting should be done first**.

Part of everybody having the power to improve posts and almost everybody being able to comment and vote is that we expect some of you to do that grunt work and improve stuff. Or prompt the poster to improve it. It's not fair to expect a very finite amount of moderator to deal with things that can be edited up.

Certainly, flagging something as being dire without also downvoting is a poor show. Why is it awful enough for us to deal with but not you?

Comment: Well, normal users can view the Low Quality Posts queue so it's not just mods who deal with this... Or am I confusing this with something else?

Comment: Probably not, but [in many cases] that's still saying "I can't be bothered to deal with this". It going through review like that just attracts more people who can't be bothered to fix it and yay, we've deleted a post :(